# Show form fields conditionally based on user input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel

In my Laravel app, I have a `select` form field that lists a set of countries:

```
<select id="js-countrySiteSelect">
    <option>Select Your Country</option>
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>Australia</option>
    <option>Germany</option>
    <option>Switzerland</option>
    <option>United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

Beneath that, I also have a series of select form fields. Each `select` shows a series of locations within that country.

```
{!! Form::select('site_id', $australia, null, ['class' => 'js-siteSelect select-australia', null => 'Select a user...']) !!}
{!! Form::select('site_id', $germany, null, ['class' => 'js-siteSelect select-germany']) !!}
{!! Form::select('site_id', $switzerland, null, ['class' => 'js-siteSelect select-switzerland']) !!}
{!! Form::select('site_id', $us, null, ['class' => 'js-siteSelect select-us']) !!}
{!! Form::select('site_id', $uk, null, ['class' => 'js-siteSelect select-uk']) !!}
```

Based on which country the user selects, I want to show or hide the corresponding form fields:

```
$('#js-countrySiteSelect').change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.js-siteSelectLabel').addClass('js-show');
  if ( $(this).val() == 'United States' ) {
    $('.js-siteSelect').removeClass('js-show');
    $('.select-us').addClass('js-show');
  } else if ( $(this).val() == 'Australia' ) {
    $('.js-siteSelect').removeClass('js-show');
    $('.select-australia').addClass('js-show');
  } else if ( $(this).val() == 'Germany' ) {
    $('.js-siteSelect').removeClass('js-show');
    $('.select-germany').addClass('js-show');
  } else if ( $(this).val() == 'Switzerland' ) {
    $('.js-siteSelect').removeClass('js-show');
    $('.select-switzerland').addClass('js-show');
  } else if ( $(this).val() == 'United Kingdom' ) {
    $('.js-siteSelect').removeClass('js-show');
    $('.select-uk').addClass('js-show');
  }
});
```

However, since each location dropdown is still loaded into the DOM, the form always submits the first option of the last `select`—in this example, the UK dropdown.

How can I refactor this so that only the visible `select` element submits data?

Comment: Instead of having a load of `elseif`'s a switch statement would clean up your code. Or better yet, add the name of the field as a data attribute to each selectable item and just JQuery select the matching item using e.g. `$(".select[data-country='Australia']").addClass('js-show')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you just hide the not used selects, if you mark them as disabled, then the elements wont be send to the server.

Try in place to set

```
$select.hide()
```

use

```
$select.prop('disabled', true)
```

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. Thanks.

Comment: @cralfaro do you hide it and disable it or just disable it?

Comment: @Marvin just disable it